# Draw each element of array in new row with DataTables (Meteor Tabular)

Tags: javascript, meteor, datatables

I am using the Meteor [Tabular package](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/tabular#aldeed-tabular) which implements [DataTables](http://datatables.net/). I am trying to create a table from a Mongo collection. The collection has one document of the form

```
{
  input: Array[365],
  output: Array[365],
  date: Array[365]
}
```

I define the table in Meteor with the following code

```
TabularTables.MyTable = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "MyTable",
    collection: MyTable,
    columns: [
        {data: "input", title: "Input", searchable: false},
        {data: "output", title: "Output", searchable: false},
        {data: "date", title: "Date", searchable: false}
    ],
    order: [[1, "desc"]],
    pageLength: 10
});
```

The problem is that when this is drawn, all 365 elements of each variable end up in a single cell, so I have one massive row. I want each element to be created in a separate row, i.e.

```
Input      Output      Date
input[0]   output[0]   date[0]
input[1]   output[1]   date[1]
```

whereas it is currently

```
Input            Output            Date
input[0...364]   output[0...364]   date[0...364]
```

Comment: Transforming your data into a list of {input:..., output:..., date:...} is affordable? If this is possible (and ok to do) it's easy for dataTable to process it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to transform your data and then put it into a local collection, since that package doesn't accept arrays (in contrary to what I thought earlier).

This seems to work:

```js
TabularTables = {};
local =  new Meteor.Collection();

var data = MyTable.findOne();
if (data) {
    local.find().forEach(function(x) { local.remove(x._id) });
    for (var i in data.input) {
        local.insert({
            input: data.input[i],
            output: data.output[i],
            date: data.date[i]
        });
    }
}

TabularTables.MyTable = new Tabular.Table({
    name: "MyTable",
    collection: local,
    columns: [
        {data: "input", title: "Input", searchable: false},
        {data: "output", title: "Output", searchable: false},
        {data: "date", title: "Date", searchable: false}
    ],
    order: [[1, "desc"]],
    pageLength: 10
});
```

Note that this may no longer be reactive. But I'm assuming that your data in those big arrays is not going to change either, or else you would probably change your schema to be more compatible with meteor to begin with. So hopefully that's not a problem.

Comment: Following your suggestion results in the error `Error: Tabular.Table options must specify collection`

Comment: oh yes, you are right. That package doesn't actually accept array (I was thinking of a different one). I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I ended up just writing a script to create a new collection directly in Mongo, the storage overhead isn't a concern so it was the easiest route.

Answer (score 1):

Since TabularTables doesn't allow for arrays, you could try and use the aslagle:reactive-table Meteor package instead. The example on the package's [git page](https://github.com/aslagle/reactive-table#nested-objects-and-arrays) shows how you can use mongo's syntax on your array.