# Template level reactivity in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, d3.js, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I'm working on a problem where I want to display data in a dashboard both as a chart (via [perak:c3](https://atmospherejs.com/perak/c3)) and in a table (via [aslagle:reactive-table](https://atmospherejs.com/aslagle/reactive-table)). My issue is that the data is pulled from a collection in MongoDB, and it's format is instantly amenable to plotting via c3, but needs to be transformed into a local collection to be used by the reactive-table package, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34866197/1521933) to a previous question.

When I change the dataset to be displayed I want the chart to be updated, and the table also. This requires changing the values in the local collection, however, which slows things down and so rather than the chart being smoothly redrawn, there is a freeze on the page, and then the new data is displayed.

I have created a sample project [on GitHub here](https://github.com/philipobrien/meteor-reactive-chart-table) so the problem can be replicated easily. If you run the app and select a dataset in your browser you will see exactly what I mean

[image]

To see the reactive behaviour I want to preserve in the chart go to `client/templates/dashboard/dashboard.html` and simply comment out the table template `{{> dashboardTable}}`

[image]

and now change the dataset to see how the chart is smoothly redrawn. Essentially I am trying to ensure both templates `dashboardChart` and `dashboardTable` render independently of one another.

---

## UPDATE

Following **Michael Floyd's** suggestion of using a timeout helped a bit

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){createLocalCollection(data)},200);
```

but although the chart gets smoothly drawn, when the table finishes being filled, the chart is drawn again. It looks like it jumps to some intermediate state that I can't understand. [Here is a video](https://vimeo.com/154603806) showing what I mean.

Comment: That HTML comment doesn't really prevent rendering template - use blaze comment instead: `{{!-- comment --}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding this as a separate answer because it's a completely different approach.

Use the `onRendered` callback in d3 to invoke the local collection update.

Where you have:

```
chart = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#dataset-chart',
```

in `dashboard_chart.js`, add:

```
chart = c3.generate({
  onrendered: createLocalCollection(),
  bindto: '#dataset-chart',
```

Of course you need to remove `createLocalCollection(data)` from your event handler.

To avoid having to pass the data context through the `onrendered` handler in d3 also update your `createLocalCollection` function to use the reactive variable `datasetID` that you defined earlier to establish the current dataset:

```
var createLocalCollection = function() {
    var values = My_First_Collection.find({datasetID: datasetID.get()}).fetch();
    var tempDoc = {};
    local.remove({});
    tempDoc = {};
    for (var i in values[0].value) {
      tempDoc.value = values[0].value[i];
      tempDoc.date = values[0].date[i];
      local.insert(tempDoc);
    }
};
```

Using this method you let D3 tell you when the chart rendering is done and then your table can start getting populated. The result is an instantaneous chart update followed by the table updating. No mucking with timeouts either.

Comment: Incidentally, you might want to rethink your local collection approach. The most expensive aspect is the `local.insert()` For one you could index that collection by the `datasetID` so that you don't need to rebuild it every time, secondly you could be caching other charts while the user is looking at the present one

Comment: That works great thanks. I also ensured that `datasetID` is indexed by including `My_First_Collection._ensureIndex({ "datasetID" : 1})` in a `Meteor.startup()` block. There is still a delay with the table, but I can live with it for now. Thank you for your help and insight.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that js is single threaded. You have two things to and they are going to happen sequentially. What you can do is *defer* the code that is updating the local collection using `Meteor.setTimeout()`. This will allow the chart to update first and then your table can update second. I've seen this before where you run a function that updates the DOM (in your case d3 is updating the svg canvas) but the actual screen update gets stuck behind long running js.

I tried this specifically and chart performance was fine.

```
Meteor.setTimeout(function(){createLocalCollection(data)},500);
```

Cutting the interval down to 100 allowed the chart to update but then the menu didn't fade out completely until the local collection finished updating.

One thing that I've used with tables and local collections is to only update the local collection document when the corresponding non-local document is being rendered on screen (assuming there's a 1:1 relationship between the original data and the transformed version). This allows the reactive table to load lazily.

Comment: So instead of having `updatePlot(data); createLocalCollection(data);` I try `updatePlot(data); Meteor.setTimeout(createLocalCollection(data), 5000);`, but this has no effect, regardless of the length of timeout used

Comment: I'll have to dig into your code to see what I can find.

Comment: `setTimeout` takes a function as the first parameter. You just needed to anonymize your call to `createLocalCollection`

Comment: That works for me if I increase the timeout. For some reason, with a timeout of `200` the chart gets drawn, then when the table finishes being filled, the chart is drawn again. It looks list it jumps to some intermediate state that I can't understand.

Comment: Glad it works! The timeout you need likely depends on machine speed.

Comment: No I think the behaviour is something else, but I'm not sure. [Here is a video of it](https://vimeo.com/154603806)

Comment: It looks like the scaling on the data is changing! It's a bit hard to tell but it's like the dynamic range changes while the shape of the curves remains the same.

Comment: It works with 500, i.e. the chart doesn't have that weird scaling jump, but with 500 the delay between the chart being updated and the table being updated is very noticeable so I was hoping to avoid this